# Constraining predicted probabilities of a poisson regression with a binary outcome

Tags: poisson-regression

I have used a modified poisson regression to model a binary outcome because I want to obtain relative risks, rather than odds ratios. The predicted probabilities are of interest, but many are beyond the range [0, 1].

Is there an appropriate way to constrain these to occur in the range [0, 1]? If a solution exists, I am keen to apply it to standard `glm` models and models generated using `glmnet` in R.

Comment: Your mathematically impossible results show forcibly why this approach is invalid.  Why don't you just do logistic regression with a log link?

Comment: You could consider a binomial model with a different link function than the logistic.